# Cannot get a <p>'s inner HTML to be changed to LocaleDateString()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a calendar as a test and I keep running into this problem. I make a variable that has a date with the method toLocaleDateString. When I try to change a paragraph's inner HTML, nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HTML Calendar</title>
    <script>
        var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="clock"></p>
    <div id="cal">
        <div id="headmonth"><p id="date"></p></div>
        <div id="days"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The element doesn't exist when your code runs.

Comment: "Nothing happens", actually something happens, you get an error message to the console saying something like  `document.getElementById("date") is null or not an object"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to select that element before the HTML is loaded. You can either move your code to the end of the page, just before the `</body>` end tag, **or** add a `window.onload` function like:

```
window.onload = function(){

        var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
}
```

Like this, using one of these options, your script will run after the HTML has been read and your selector will find the HTML.

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkdj9/1/) using code in end of `<body>`
**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkdj9/)** using code in the window.onload function

Comment: Using `window.onload` will only call this script after all images, scripts, css, html, etc. have been loaded. It's not a good solution for this case.

Comment: @Gavin, I added another option also, to have the code in the end of the body also.

Comment: I know. Just want to make it clear what `window.onload` actually does, since many people think it's the same as the DOM being ready.

Comment: Oh gosh. Now I see the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `script` right before the closing `</body>` tag. Also, I suggest using this approach to make sure that your script executes *after* the document is ready:

```
function init() {
    var date = ...
    // your code here
}

window.onload = init;
```

If you're using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = ...;
    // your code
}
```

The reason why your current code does not work, is because since you place your `script` in the `head`, the browser hasn't loaded all the `<body>` stuff yet. So your script doesn't know about that `p` element, and does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.onload`. That will only be called once ALL content is loaded, including images. There will be a noticeable delay between when the page first opens and your date element is updated.

You can just include your javascript at the bottom of your document, before `</body>`, like others have suggested, but if you want to keep all your script in your `<head>` you can detect when the DOM is ready. jQuery does a great job at detecting when the DOM is ready. I've isolated their code below, which is pure javascript (no jQuery) and cross-browser compatible.

```
<script>
    // Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
    if ( document.addEventListener ) {
        // Use the handy event callback
        document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            document.removeEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false );
            init();
        }, false );

    // If IE event model is used
    } else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
        // ensure firing before onload,
        // maybe late but safe also for iframes
        document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
            if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
                document.detachEvent( "onreadystatechange", arguments.callee );
                init();
            }
        });
    }

    function init()
    {
        var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
    }
</script>
```

[**Example jsFiddle of this approach**](http://jsfiddle.net/kBX4V/)